# spring-cloud-gateway FallBackHeaders missing exception details

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I a using spring-cloud-gateway for the first time and new to reactive world as well so it is possible i am missing something. I have configured CircuitBreaker and it works properly. I have a fallback uri which is inside the controller of my gateway. I want to throw the original exception but want to capture that exception as well, probably for metrics. So i configured fallbackHeaders. So the `SpringCloudCircuitBreakerFilter` is invoked first and it calls the service with `CircuitBreaker`. If an exception is thrown I was expecting it will invoke the `addExceptionDetails` method first and then will invoke `FallbackHeadersGatewayFilter` but it seems like it invokes `FallbackHeadersGatewayFilter` and then adds the exception. Can someone help me understand if this is the right behavior and if it is how do I get the exception(other than writing my own filter). Here is the router config:

```
 .filters(spec -> spec.filters(filters)
                    .circuitBreaker(c -> {
                                c.setRouteId(route.getRouteId());
                                c.setName("slow");
                                c.setFallbackUri("forward:/fallback");
                                c.addStatusCode("400");
                                c.addStatusCode("404");
                                c.addStatusCode("500");
                            }
                            )
                    .fallbackHeaders(config -> {
                        config.setExecutionExceptionMessageHeaderName("message-header");
                        config.setExecutionExceptionTypeHeaderName("type-header");
                        config.setRootCauseExceptionMessageHeaderName("root-cause-message-header");
                        config.setRootCauseExceptionTypeHeaderName("root-cause-type-header");
                    }
                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been learning how to use CircuitBreaker, and here is what I have found.  Hopefully it will be helpful to you.

1. Since your Fallback URI is inside the controller of your gateway, I think you can get the exception from the ServerWebExchange

   - [Documentation here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#spring-cloud-circuitbreaker-filter-factory) (right above 6.5.1)
   - My example code written in Kotlin:

   ```
   @GetMapping("/fallback")
   fun fallbackEndpoint(serverWebExchange: ServerWebExchange):
       ResponseEntity<String> {
       val exception: Exception? = serverWebExchange
           .getAttribute(ServerWebExchangeUtils.CIRCUITBREAKER_EXECUTION_EXCEPTION_ATTR)
   ```
2. In your example, the CircuitBreaker and FallBackHeaders seem to be on the same endpoint. I think that the FallbackHeaders are meant to be used on a different endpoint than the one with the CircuitBreaker

   - I think they should be added as a filter to the external fallback endpoint
   - It's not Reactive, but please see [this example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#fallback-headers) for context (the CircuitBreaker and FallBackHeaders are used on different endpoints)

Comment: Would appreciate if you could please accept my answer.  Thank you!